# Removing whitespace in a block in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this:

```
= link_to user_path(f.object.user) do
  %span.hourly-rate>= f.object.user.hourly_rate.to_currency
  \/hour
```

Which renders as:

```
<a href="/users/44"><span class='hourly-rate'>$16</span>/hour
</a>
```

The close tag is on a separate line. This results in the link looking funny when there is underlining (eg. on hover)

[image: The underlining goes for one character too long]

The solution is to have the markup look like:

```
<a href="/users/44"><span class='hourly-rate'>$16</span>/hour</a>
```

But I haven't found a way of doing that in Haml. I'd prefer to keep using the block form of `link_to` if possible (I imagine not using the block would result in even messier code, but at this point I'm open to anything).

**Tangent**: I imagine this would be fixed if I was using the `:ugly` Haml option. I have `Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true` in my `config/environments/development.rb`, and I have `haml-rails` in my Gemfile (I know it doesn't include `:ugly`, but it's worth mentioning), and I have an initializer with;

```
# config/initializers/haml.rb
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :html5
Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true
```

... but the code still isn't ugly :( Any ideas why not?

Comment: How are you styling the links? I suspect that this may be easier to solve by changing your css rather than your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The span was being used by javascript, to get its value (in this case, the user's hourly rate) - it wasn't being used for CSS at all.

Thus, I ended up removing the span and adding the user's hourly rate as a `data-` attribute of a separate field. So the final markup for the link was

```
= link_to f.object.user.hourly_rate.to_currency + "/hour", user_path(f.object.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the content wrapped inside another `div`, you can use this:

```
= link_to user_path(f.object.user) do
  %div<>
    %span.hourly-rate>= f.object.user.hourly_rate.to_currency
    \/hour
```

Comment: That would work but it's not ideal. I suppose I'll have to go with it if there is no other way. The other thing I thought of is writing all the HTML by hand, but neither is appealing.